# ApplicationState data in angularjs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

In an MVC application, we store some `ApplicationState` data like `UserDisplayName`, `Roles` etc in a model. They are collected from `HttpContext.Current` or `Thread.Current`.

Injected into each controller, we have access to those info on each different view.

But what is the best practice to share those info in different `AngularJS` views? Should I store a vm in `$rootScope`, or `HTML5` local storage, or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd use a service to retrieve/set the data whenever needed, services are good for more reasons though, you can do a two-way data binding between controllers, they are easy injectable into other controllers/services/factories, they are singletons and the data will be there easy accessible until you refresh page

Comment: Does it mean we have to request for application state data on each angular view?

Comment: So your suggested solution is to add an ApiController to GET and UPDATE those application info (placed in a model). Then the angular service to call that ApiController to access data. Isn't it?